# Prepopulate the field twice

Tags: entities

I'm using [Entityreference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module. Is there way to pre-populate the field more than once?

**Example:**

```
example.com/add/node/custom&field_venue=92,92,92,183
```

I want the field venue to prepopulate 3 times. I can only do this if I type in the referenced node on the field, but I want it to prepopulate from the URL.

Comment: Do you mean display if so you could try tokens

Comment: No. I dont mean display, I was talking about the form when creating a node.

Example URL:www.testsite.com/add/node/custom&field_venue=92,92,92,183

I'm using entityreference prepopulate, and I want the field_venue to prepopulate '92' 3 times on the form.

Answer (score 0):

D7; Just adjust your contentype, fields names, and token.

```
<a class="your_class" href="node/add/your_node_type?field_1=[token]&field_2=[token]&field_3=[token]">Your title</a>
```